# Counting in MySQL and looping it

Tags: mysql

Let's say I'm trying to display the number of views(user will click the "viewed" button which will send the PostID and userID to the tb_views database

```
(SELECT COUNT(Viewed) FROM tb_views WHERE Viewed = 6) AS ViewCount,
```

It works fine as the count will be counted for postID "6"
And I will run the statement through a while loop which means if there are 10 posts, 10 posts will be displayed

Problem now is how do I assign the "Viewed =" to a dynamic form where it will automatically change for every post that's generated? Currently if I set it to "6", all the 10 posts echoing $ViewCount will show the number of views for posts 6 and not their post

I can do it for the posts where the PostID and everything will generated properly with the loop

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, everything else works like echoing out the PostID and stuff for the posts generated by the while loop. Just that I can't figure out how to make the "Viewed =" dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Viewed, COUNT(Viewed) FROM tb_views GROUP BY Viewed
```

try this code. You can also combine group by statement with where conditions but if you want to get the counts of views for every postid then this is the query for you if your going to use where condition and just for 1 postid then its not necessary for you to use group by anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot! http://i.imgur.com/dpRB0nB.png Now it's closer than ever! But how do I echo out properly for the posts accordingly?

Comment: I think that comes conveniently by looping through the values returned by the query and processing it accordingly it can either be on php or maybe you can use json_encode then iterate through the values using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a multiple JOIN query. Here's an example, that should be close to what you're looking for:

```
$sql = "SELECT tb_users.sName, tb_users.sCountry, COUNT(tb_views.Viewed) AS ViewCount, tb_posts.id AS postID
               tb_posts.sPost, tb_posts.sPlace, tb_posts.Time, tb_posts.iUserID
        FROM tb_posts 
        LEFT JOIN tb_views ON tb_views.postID = tb_posts.id 
        LEFT JOIN tb_users ON tb_posts.userID = tb_users.id
        ORDER BY id desc";
$mysqli ->  prepare ($sql);
```

Make sure to double check that all the tables and values are correct, since I can't see what your database actually looks like, I had to guess ;)

Here's a version using aliases, which makes it a bit cleaner:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.sName, u.sCountry, COUNT(v.Viewed) AS ViewCount, p.id AS postID
               p.sPost, p.sPlace, p.Time, p.iUserID
        FROM tb_posts AS p
        LEFT JOIN tb_views AS v ON v.postID = p.id 
        LEFT JOIN tb_users AS u ON p.userID = u.id
        ORDER BY id desc";
$mysqli ->  prepare ($sql);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I think it's because I'm preparing the id FROM tb_posts in that statement and I can't get the "$postID"(or rather "$id") in the same statement, do I have to create another statement below it?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you try re-phrasing that?

Comment: You're doing a WHERE Viewed = " . $postID . " right? But where is the $postID from?

Comment: Ah, so you don't know postID yet? Are you trying to get the viewcount for just one post? Or are you trying to get viewcounts for all posts?

Comment: I will know the postID after I run that because it's at the back(right after the ViewCount) WHERE Viewed = " . $postID . " AS ViewCount, HERE <id> HERE, sPost, sPlace, iTime, iUserID FROM tb_posts ORDER BY id DESC"; so right now the Viewed = " . $postID . " has no postID unless I create another statement below it so I will already have the ID after the statement right?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're looking for. See edit above. You'll probably have to clean that up, but that's the general idea.